# Pandas - Join multiple rows into one row with more columns

Tags: python, pandas

I've done some searching and can't find this.  I may not be using the correct wording.

This is what I want to do:

```
id, C1, C2
0,   1,  2
1,   2,  3
2,   2,  4
3,   5,  6
4,   7,  8
5,   9, 10
6,  11, 12
7,  13, 14
```

Into this (x rows (in this case 3) into 1 row with multiple columns):

```
id, C1, C2, C1_1, C2_1, C1_2, C2_2
0,   1,  2,    3,    4,    5,    6
1,   7,  8,    9,   10,   11,   12
2,  13, 14,  Nan,  Nan,  NaN,  NaN
```

it's okay if i need to drop the rows that would result in NaN.

I could write some kind of loop, but it seems like there would be a good pandas way to this, i'm just not finding it.

Comment: Your question isn't clear, could you explain more? Are you talking about transpose of dataframe?

Comment: Yes, something like transpose, but it looks like transpose only transposes the entire dataset.  I want every 3 rows transposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need create two type id , one by mod one by `cumcount`, then do `pivot_table`

```
df.id=df.id//3+1
df['id1']=df.groupby('id').cumcount()

s=df.pivot_table(index='id1',columns='id',values=['C1','C2'],aggfunc='sum').sort_index(level=1,axis=1)
      C1   C2   C1    C2    C1    C2
id     1    1    2     2     3     3
id1                                 
0    1.0  2.0  5.0   6.0  11.0  12.0
1    2.0  3.0  7.0   8.0  13.0  14.0
2    2.0  4.0  9.0  10.0   NaN   NaN
```